# pandas get next day in intraday data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example: I have intraday dataframe (no freqency in days)

```
df =                  Column
Date
2005-01-03 08:00:00   88.6008
2005-01-03 08:01:00   88.5571
2005-01-03 08:02:00   88.5571
2005-01-03 08:03:00   88.5717
2005-01-03 08:04:00   88.5644
...                       ...
2021-10-08 19:54:00  437.3900
2021-10-08 19:56:00  437.3900
2021-10-08 19:58:00  437.3700
2021-10-08 19:59:00  437.3500
2021-10-08 20:00:00  437.8600
```

And i need to do something with all days except some special days like

```
special days = Index(['2007-07-27', '2007-08-10', '2008-08-18', '2008-09-10', '2008-09-19',
       '2008-09-22', '2008-09-29', '2008-10-01', '2008-10-14', '2008-10-15',
       '2008-11-20', '2008-11-21', '2008-11-24', '2008-12-01', '2008-12-02',
       '2008-12-15', '2008-12-22', '2009-01-09', '2009-01-15', '2009-01-20',
       '2009-02-18', '2009-03-30', '2009-04-17', '2009-05-12', '2009-07-02',
       '2009-11-19', '2010-01-28', '2010-05-04', '2010-05-14', '2010-08-18',
       '2010-09-28', '2011-03-10', '2011-08-09', '2011-08-10', '2011-09-09',
       '2011-09-13', '2011-10-05', '2011-10-07', '2011-10-25', '2012-11-07',
       '2015-01-12', '2015-01-22', '2015-04-01', '2015-08-25', '2015-08-26',
       '2016-01-14', '2018-02-09', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-10', '2020-03-13',
       '2020-03-17', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-23', '2020-04-07', '2020-04-13',
       '2020-05-04', '2020-06-29', '2020-09-21', '2020-11-06', '2020-11-09',
       '2021-01-27', '2021-01-29'],
      dtype='object')
```

Well, only now noticed that i didnt make them DatetimeIndex by to_datetime(), nevermind, I'll make it.

So... I can make something like this: `tmp_df = df.loc[:special_days[0]]`
Do something to that part, then do something to that part: `tmp_df[special_days[0]]`
And finally, I need next day of `special_days[0]` but to be sure that next day will be in dataframe data and loc from the next day till special_days[1] and do whatever I want.

Well, i know, there is some kind of easy solution like split my original data in parts something like this:

```
df_normal_days = df[~df.index.isin(special_days)]
df_special_days = df[df.index.isin(special_days)]
```

and iterate over pairs of dates, but is there any way to get next day? Like get_loc or something :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
special_days = pd.to_datetime(special_days)
idx_norm = df.index.normalize()

for days in zip(special_days, special_days[1:]):
    print (days)
    df_special_days = df[idx_norm.isin(days)]
```

Comment: @Eugene - What is expected ouput? for each pair new dataframe? Like first `['2007-07-27', '2007-08-10']`, second `['2008-08-18', '2008-09-10']` ... ?

Comment: @Eugene What does _"no freqency in days"_ mean?

Comment: @jezrael - Expected output for each iteration:
1st iteration [next_day('2007-07-27') , '2007-08-10']
2nd iteration [next_day('2007-08-10') , '2007-08-18']
and so on
So the basic output I need is to get next day of speial day and next special day

Comment: @Timus - that means that if I have 2020-01-02 that means original dataframe not necessary contain 2020-01-03, there is gaps in dates. There is no freq='D' or 'B'.

Comment: @Eugene - answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael - Thanks! Different approach I expected, but it gives me new opportunities and really comfortable to use. Thanks again! 

By the way, is there any fast way  or standardizied way to solve that problem:
I have day and intraday data, I need to get next day that my intraday data contains. <pre>df[df.index.date > day.date()].index[0] <code> Maybe some kind like this? What you think?

Comment: @Eugene - Do you think `df[df.shift().index.date > day.date()].index` or ` `df[df.shift(-1).index.date > day.date()].index` ?